# error creating a neural network model in r

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, model

I'm trying to create a neural network model with a dataset that has 4 numeric columns and 3 text column, i used embbedings on the text and scaled the numeric columns and now trying to implement the model:

```
max_features <- 10000
words_embed_dim <- 50
n_cells <- 4

tokenizer <- text_tokenizer(num_words = max_features)
tokenizer %>% fit_text_tokenizer(unique(c(combined_tr$description, combined_tr$ingredients, combined_tr$household_serving_fulltext)))

description <- texts_to_sequences(tokenizer, combined_tr$description)
ingredients <- texts_to_sequences(tokenizer, combined_tr$ingredients)
household_serving_fulltext <- texts_to_sequences(tokenizer, combined_tr$household_serving_fulltext)
```

```
seq_len = 4
description_padded <- pad_sequences(description, maxlen = seq_len, value = max_features + 1)
ingredients_padded <- pad_sequences(ingredients, maxlen = seq_len, value = max_features + 1)
household_serving_fulltext_padded <- pad_sequences(household_serving_fulltext, maxlen = seq_len, value = max_features + 1)
```

```
normalized_data <- scale(combined_tr[, c("red", "green", "blue", 'encoded_Text_Found')])
```

```
input1 <- layer_input(shape = c(seq_len), name = "input_description")
input2 <- layer_input(shape = c(seq_len), name = "input_ingredients")
input3 <- layer_input(shape = c(seq_len), name = "input_household_serving_fulltext")
numeric_input <- layer_input(shape = c(seq_len), name = "numeric_input")
```

```
word_embedder <- layer_embedding(
  input_dim = max_features + 2,
  output_dim = words_embed_dim,
  input_length = seq_len,
  embeddings_regularizer = regularizer_l2(0.0001)
)

seq_embedder <- layer_lstm(
  units = n_cells,
  kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l2(0.0001)
)
```

```
description_embed <- input1 %>% word_embedder() %>% seq_embedder()
ingredients_embed <- input2 %>% word_embedder() %>% seq_embedder()
household_serving_embed <- input3 %>% word_embedder() %>% seq_embedder()
# Concatenate all inputs
combined_input <- layer_concatenate(c(description_embed, ingredients_embed, household_serving_embed, numeric_input))


#concatenated_input <- layer_concatenate(c(description_embed, ingredients_embed, household_serving_embed, numeric_input))

y <- to_categorical((combined_tr$encoded_category - 1), num_classes = 6)

# Fully connected layers
fully_connected <- concatenated_input %>%
  layer_dense(units = n_cells, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dense(units = n_cells, activation = "relu")

# Output layer for classification
output <- fully_connected %>%
  layer_dense(units = num_classes, activation = "softmax")  # Adjust num_classes based on your dataset

# Create the model
model <- keras_model(inputs = c(input1, input2, input3, numeric_input), outputs = output)

model %>%
  compile(
    loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
    optimizer = optimizer_adam(),
    metrics = c("accuracy")
  )

history <- model %>% fit(
  x = list(description_padded, ingredients_padded, household_serving_fulltext_padded, normalized_data),
  y = y,
  epochs = 10,  
  batch_size = 32,
  validation_split = 0.2
)
```

I seem to get an error in this part:

> model <- keras_model(inputs = c(input1, input2, input3, numeric_input), outputs = output)
> Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) :
> ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name='numeric_input'), name='numeric_input', description="created by layer 'numeric_input'") at layer "reshape_3". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

i cannot seem to match the different types of columns into the same shape, and when i force it i get this error.

Comment: Please provide some insight (and check yourself) if what you're feeding the model indeed has the structure you expect to be feeding the model. Example: `x = list(description_padded, ingredients_padded, household_serving_fulltext_padded, normalized_data)` seems to be a list of three vectors and a three-column dataframe. Does `x = c(list(description_padded, ingredients_padded, household_serving_fulltext_padded), as.list(normalized_data))` work?